# Why are $ \lim\limits_{n \to \infty } 1^n = 1$ and $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty } 0^n = 0$ not indeterminate?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm working with series and for some reason, it seems that these two limits stop being indeterminate when n is a positive integer. Why is that true ?

Comment: Since $1^n=1$ and $0^n=0$, these are *constant* sequences. Why should the limit of a constant sequence be indeterminate?

Comment: Makes sense said this way. I guess I was mistaking constant and approaching a certain value.

Comment: A related, and interesting, question is the form $0^0$.  You can find long, pointless and tedious arguments about it.  Maybe we would say: $0^0=1$ when the exponent is the integer zero, but $0^0$ is undefined when the exponent is the real number zero.  But that would cause even more long, pointless, and tedious arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it's clear now!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeterminate forms are indeterminate when both parts are varying.  For example, with indeterminate form
$$
{1}^{\infty}
$$
it is true that when the base does not vary, we have
$$
\lim_{x \to +\infty}{1}^{x} = 1
$$
But exponent "positive integer" has nothing to do with it:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n = e
$$

Answer (score 4):

When you write it as $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} 1^n$, you are asking for the limit of the sequence $\{1,1,1,\ldots\}$, which is $1$.

The issue arises when the "$1$" is approaching one but not equal to $1$. So when we talk about the indeterminate form $1^\infty$, that is short hand for the limit of a sequence like $\{(1+1/n)^n\}$. One might be tempted to say that the inside goes to $1$, so sequence eventually looks like $\{1^n\}$. On the other hand, as the exponent gets larger, one might expect the values to blow up. Neither is not true, and the limit actually goes to $e$.